# Can't compile windows driver - Signability test fails for windows driver

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdk, wdf

I'm trying to create a very simple windows driver, the problem is that I can't get to compile it, visual studio keeps giving me the following error:

> kmd\kmd.inf does not have NTAMD64 decorated model sections.

What's causing this problem and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like your INF file may be missing the .ntamd64 section. Please take a look at the following Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-file-platform-extensions-and-x64-based-systems

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't there a way to make visual studio automate that? I refuse to believe it poses such a hurdle for driver developers...

Comment: @Tery No such automation exist in Visual Studio.  Anyway such automation would not make much sense as Visual Studio would not know what to put there as it would not the information specific to your driver and device.